# VBA Code for Vlookup across multiple worksheets within the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to coding, therefore require some assistance.

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets, which hold Names in column A & addresses in column B.

I am attempting to do the following:

```
If worksheets("Input").Range("A1").Value
```

is present on any of the other worksheets (A to Z) then

```
worksheets("Input").Range("B1").Value = Cell.value
```

that is next to cell that matches

```
worksheets("Input").Range("A1").Value
```

i.e.-

```
if worksheet("B").Range("A1").Value = worksheets("Input").Range("A1").Value,  
   then worksheets("Input").Range("B1").Value = worksheet("B").Range("B1").Value
```

Can anyone explain how I would do this in vba without having to use a lot of IFs per worksheet?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: " is present on any of the other worksheets (A to Z) " what do you mean by this?, is the value `worksheets("Input").Range("A1").Value` present in a specific column of any of the worksheet or you have to find it in the whole worksheet?

Comment: how many other sheet you have? I mean the number of sheet you want to look for the value, because your question has a loop hole, when you said "is present on any of the other worksheets (A to Z) ", this includes the current worksheet 'input'

Comment: there is 27 sheets all together, first sheet is call Input, where I update that one sheet, the rest are named A through to Z. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it with a small example with one 'input' sheet and two other sheet (A and B as in you case) the layout is something like this [image: sheet_input-before] ,[image: Sheet-input_after], [image: sheet-A],[image: sheet-B] the loop for `vlookup` starts for the 2nd row of the column A of input sheet...

```
Sub foo()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim key As String
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim wksName As Variant
Dim LastRow As Integer


Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

With wkb.Sheets("Input")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' totol number of entries in col A of input sheet
End With

' for each name in input sheet's column-A search the name in all sheets other then input sheet
For rowIndex = 2 To LastRow Step 1
  key = wkb.Worksheets("Input").Cells(rowIndex, 1).Value ' name to search
    For Each wks In wkb.Worksheets ' loop through all the sheets
        If Not wks.Name = "Input" Then ' avoid searching in input sheet itself
          On Error Resume Next ' to search next sheet when not found in current one
          wkb.Worksheets("Input").Cells(rowIndex, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(key, wks.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
       End If
    Next wks
Next rowIndex

End Sub
```

update 1 >

```
Sub foo()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim key As String
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim wksName As Variant
Dim LastRow As Integer


Set wkb = ThisWorkbook



' for name in input sheet's A1 cell, search the name in all sheets other then input sheet

  key = wkb.Worksheets("Input").Range("A1").Value ' name to search
    For Each wks In wkb.Worksheets ' loop through all the sheets
        If Not wks.Name = "Input" Then ' avoid searching in input sheet itself
          On Error Resume Next ' to search next sheet when not found in current one
          wkb.Worksheets("Input").Range("B1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(key, wks.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
       End If
    Next wks

End Sub
```

Comment: Thats a great start, thanks. what if I wanted to only search for the value from one cell on sheet (Input), say range(A1), but this value can be changed.

Comment: you mean only a single entry in input sheet, (in cell A1 of the input sheet)

Comment: @AndrewBooth the code in update 1, searches entry of cell A1 of sheet one in all the sheets and paste the result to sell B1 of the input sheet

Comment: that is absolutely perfect, all credit goes to you. Thank you.